# Working with Radio Buttons on Flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

Just started my first app in React and I want to know if there is a React way to work with Radio Buttons, I have a form with 4 radio buttons, I need to take 2 of the options selected and send that info to a backend.

```
class RadioBtns extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      greet : '',
      hello : '',
    };
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <form>
            <input type="radio" value="first" name="greet" onChange={this._onChangeGreet}/> Option 1
            <input type="radio" value="second" name="greet" onChange={this._onChangeGreet}/> Option 2
            <input type="radio" value="three" name="hello" onChange={this._onChangeHello}/> Option 3
            <input type="radio" value="four" name="hello" onChange={this._onChangeHello}/> Option 4
          </form>
          <hr />
          <button type="submit" onClick={this._submitSettings}>YES!</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  _onChangeGreet = ({ target }) => {
      this.setState({
        greet : target.value,
      });
  }

  _onChangeHello = ({ target }) => {
      this.setState({
        hello : target.value,
      });
  }

  _submitSettings = () => {
    console.log('submit');
  }

}

export default RadioBtns;
```

how do I send this states with the values to the stores ?

and here I have the action

```
@createActions(flux)
class RadioBtnsActions {

  constructor () {
    this.generateActions('optionSelected');
  }
}

export default RadioBtnsActions;
```

and in the Store

```
import flux from 'flux';
import RadioBtnsActions from 'actions/RadioBtnsActions';

@createStore(flux)
class RadioBtnsStore {
  constructor () {
    this.state = {
      radioSelected : false,
    };
  }

  @bind(RadioBtnsActions.optionSelected)
  optionSelected (option) {
    this.setState({
      radioSelected : option,
    });
  }
}

export default RadioBtnsStore;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what we did in our project (simplified, use your imagination):

First you create a RadioButton component that renders the actual input:

```
render(){
  <div>
     <input id={this.props.id} type="radio"
       name={this.props.name} value={this.props.value}
       checked={this.props.checked} onChange={this.onChange}/>
     <label htmlFor={this.props.id}>{this.props.label}</label>
 </div>
},

onChange: function(ev){
    this.props.onChange(ev.target.checked, this.props.value);
}
```

Then you use that to implement a RadioButtonGroup component:

```
render: function(){
    var name = this.name, value = this.props.value, onChange = this.onSingleRadioChange;
    var options = _.map(this.props.options, function(option){
        var id = name + '-' + option.value;
        return <RadioButton key={option.value} id={id} name={name} value={option.value} label={option.label} checked={option.value == value} onChange={onChange} />
    });

    return  <div>{options}</div>
},

onSingleRadioChange: function(checked, value){
    if(checked)
        this.props.onChange(value);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
<RadioButtonGroup name='greet' options={[{value: 'first', label: 'First'}, {value: 'second', label: 'Second'}]} onChange={val => { Actions.radioGroupChanged('greet', val);}}  />
```

Where `Actions.radioGroupChanged` is the action that your store is listening on.

Don't forget to use [labels](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) for better UX.

Edit: here's a rough draft of the store, although we use Reflux, so it's a different API that what you have:

```
var store = Reflux.createStore({
    radioGroups: {greet: 'first', hello: 'three'}, //state of the radio button groups lives here

    init(){
      this.listenTo(Actions.radioGroupChanged, this.onRadioGroupChanged);
    },

    onRadioGroupChanged(group, value){
      this.radioGroups[group] = value;
      this.trigger(); //this notifies the component that the store changed;
    }
});
```

The component then listens to the store and updates its own state:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.listenTo(store, () => { this.setState({radios: store.groups}) });
}

render(){
   return <RadioButtonGroup name='greet' value={this.state.radios.greet} .../>
}
```

Comment: can you show me the store and the action ? that's the part which got me confused.

Comment: The store and the action are not specific to the radio buttons, they're specific to your screen. In Flux, the data flow loop goes like this: Component -> Action -> Store -> Component. In your case, you'll want to pass an action into the radio button onChange handler. The radio button will trigger this action with the new value. The store listens to this action and, when it happens, updates its own internal data and signals a change. The component listens to the store and, in response to its change, updates its own state (this.setState). This triggers a re-render of the component.